# Create Session in Servlet and Use in JSP pages?

Tags: java, session, servlets

I want Create Session in CheckForLogin Servlet and Use it in all JSP pages(For checking).
What should Write in my JSP pages and instead of ......... in Sevlet.How to define Session in Servlet?

```
public void service(ServletRequest request,
                    ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if (email.equals("") || password.equals("") || email == null || password == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp?err=enterdata").forward(request,response);
    } else {
        UserBl userBl = new UserBl();
        if (userBl.checkUser(email, password)) {
            ..........................
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp?err=nulluser").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Should Write HttpServletRequest instead of ServletRequest and HttpServletResponse instead of ServletResponse in method parameters and then Create Session and access to session

Answer (score 0):

`session` is jsp implicit variable using which you get session in JSP page.

example:

```
 <%
      String temp=session.getAttribute( "tvName");
    %>
```

or using EL

```
<c:out value="${session.getAttribute("name")}"/>
```

Note: Using scriptlets in JSP pages is not good practice.

Comment: How to define Session in Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use `<%= request.getSession() %>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `${sessionScope.sessionAttributeName}` in Expression Language in JSP code.

Comment: I Should Write HttpServletRequest instead of ServletRequest and HttpServletResponse instead of ServletResponse in method parameters

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `include` instead of `forward`

Answer (score 0):

you should use this line

```
Session httpsession = request.getSession();
```

This line will create a new session object for you if one doesn't exist or it will return the existing session associated with the same client .

Answer (score 0):

to get existing session use

`HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);`